# Store Array in PlayerPrefX in Unity JS

Tags: arrays, string, unity-game-engine

In Unity Javascript, I cant make PlayerPrefsX to store Array of Strings.

Here are the requirements-

1. I have an Array of Strings.
2. Doing **Array Push** in that.
3. Now I want to store the item in PlayerPrefX

What I did is-

> var storedScoresArr:Array = new
> Array();
>
> storedScoresArr.Push(scoreDetails);
>
> PlayerPrefsX.SetStringArray("ScoreDetails",
> storedScoresArr);    // Gives Error

**P.S**
I know if I do like the following, it will work; but cant do an Array Push.-

> var storedScoresArr:String[] = ["abc", "xyz"];    // it will work
>
> // But
> doesn't support ARRAY PUSH

Please help with any workaround or if there is any way to convert the Array to String[] just before storing in PlayerPrefsX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick this in PlayerPrefsX.js

```
static function SetStringArray (key : String, array : Array) : boolean {
    if(array.length == 0) {
        Debug.LogError ("The array cannot have 0 entries when setting " + key);
        return false;
    }
    var stringArray : String[] = new String[array.length];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        stringArray[i] = array[i].ToString();

    return  SetStringArray(key, stringArray);
}
```